# How to make position_dodge and scale_x_date work together?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, posixct

I've reached the following difficulty while using ggplot2. I am trying to create a bar chart with a time-series dataset displaying both the values for each bar AND a nice date format under the x-axis. The issue is that:

- to be set into or above the bars, position_dodge must be used BUT this function only allows non-POSIXct variables
- the go-to function for dates in the x-axis is scale_x_date which requires a POSIXct variable

How do I solve this issue?

```
df <- data.frame(period = c("2019-01-01", "2019-02-01","2019-01-01","2019-02-01"),
variable = c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
value = c(100,88, 99,77))

df$period_d <- as.POSIXct(df$period)
```

This works well (but without dates in the x-axis).

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=period, y=value, group= variable, fill=variable))+
      geom_col(position= "dodge")+
      geom_text(aes(x=period, y=value,label=value),  
                position = position_dodge(1))
```

This works well but with the value in the wrong place

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=period_d, y=value, group= variable, fill=variable))+
      geom_col(position= "dodge")+
     scale_x_datetime(labels=date_format("%b-%y"),
                       breaks = date_breaks("1 month"))
```

But mixing the two is a failure. If using a POSIXct variable, the labels are not where they are meant to be and if using the character variable you reach this error message: "Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only"

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is POSIXct for *datetimes* and the Date class for *dates* (without timestamps). The latter is discrete, so you can use it with barcharts and dodge; the former is continuous, so you can't.

```
df$date = as.Date(df$period_d)

ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=value, group= variable, fill=variable))+
    geom_col(position= "dodge")+
    geom_text(aes(x=date, y=value,label=value),
            # you are drawing one set of bars for every 30 days
            # and geom_col is using the whole space by default.
            position = position_dodge(width = 30)) +
    scale_x_date()
```

[image]

You can make this look nicer by drawing thinner bars:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=value, group= variable, fill=variable))+
    geom_col(position= "dodge", width = 5)+
    geom_text(aes(x=date, y=value,label=value),
            # you are drawing one set of bars for every 30 days
            position = position_dodge(width = 5)) +
    scale_x_date()
```

[image: IMprov]